# If I want to identify a suitable control from a large number of time series, is dynamic time warping a good approach?

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference, dynamic-time-warping

To test for causality with time series I need a time series with a parallel trend to my treatment group.

Is dynamic time warping an appropriate measure to identify a potential control or is there another more appropriate method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think you need to find such control via prior knowledge. What does dynamic time warping has to do with this identification?

Comment: I have hundreds of potential controls and not enough knowledge about what is appropriate. I wondered if there was a systematic method for testing if something was suitable?

Comment: I don't think so without any prior knowledge. Take as as an example a function that is constant if the individual is treated, and has a different shape if the same individual is in the control group. It would not be possible to relate the two groups by just looking at the shapes of the time series.

Comment: Did this answer you question? If so, I'm writing the same in the answers so you can close the question